# Some adjustments in smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I want to make some adjustments in [smartdiagram](/questions/tagged/smartdiagram). Two issues:

1. How to increase the size of connecting arrows.
2. How to properly adjust the node text in centered circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\smartdiagramset{set color list = {orange!60, green!50!lime!60, magenta!60, blue!50!cyan},
uniform connection color = false,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
    /tikz/satellite/.append style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, text width=20mm},
}

\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
Criteria for Selecting Conditionalities, Relevance, Feasibility, Measurable, Non-\\discrimatory, Affordable, Acceptable
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the distance between the center node and the surrounding nodes using the option `distance planet-satellite` which will make the arrows longer. As for the misalignment (which is because the last word is longer than the `\linewidth` inside the node) you can decrease the `inner sep` of the center node and/or increase its width:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
    set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60, magenta!60, blue!50!cyan},
    distance planet-satellite=5cm,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
    /tikz/planet/.append style={text width=3cm, inner sep=5pt},
    /tikz/satellite/.append style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, text width=20mm},
}

\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
    Criteria for Selecting Conditionalities, 
    Relevance, Feasibility, Measurable, Non-\\discrimatory, Affordable, Acceptable
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Thanks @JaperHabicht for very useful answer.

Comment: Note: Due to some erratic definition in the package, explicitly stating `uniform connection color=false` will result in an error, but it is set to false by default anyways.

Comment: @JaperHabicht: I do have a [similar question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681792/4821).